# Disaggregating (interpolating) annual data to quarterly data with R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, cubic-spline

My data takes the following form:

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(1992:2015), share=c(31.9,   36.8,   38.2,   39.9,   36.3,   36.5,   35.6,   35.2,   34.8,   33.2,   33.5,   34.6,   
                                            36.3,   36.2, 38.1, 37.2,   35.9,   33.2,   36.9,   36.0,   33.9,   33.7,   34.3,   35.1))
```

The data consists of **average** annual values. I want to convert the data into **average** quarterly values, assuming that the change is linear.

I tried using the `library("tempdisagg")` , but I can't get it to work. I've also tried some other approaches with `library("splines")` in stats, but to no avail. Perhaps because I'm handling the date and time-series format incorrectly.

To clarify, the expected output would look something like this:

```
y_q     share
1992q1  values
1992q2  values
1992q3  values
1992q4  values
1993q1  values
1993q2  values
1993q3  values
1993q4  values
1994q1  values
1994q2  values
1994q3  values
1994q4  values
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "approx" function can perform the linear interpolation of the values which are required for output.

```
#create sequence of dates
quarter<-seq(as.Date("1992-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-01"), by="quarter")
#create the linear interploated values
estshare<-approx(df$share, n=length(quarter))
newdf<-data.frame(quaters<-quarter, share<-estshare$y)
```

In this case I am assumed the share prices were from the first day of the year.  If it was the average you may want to change the starting and ending date of the date sequence, "quarter" from the first of the year to mid year.

Answer (score 0):

With a linear annual interpolation you can try this with base package :

```
    annual <- data.frame(year=c(1992:2015), share=c(31.9, 36.8, 38.2, 39.9,  36.3, 36.5, 35.6, 35.2, 34.8, 33.2, 33.5, 34.6, 36.3, 36.2, 38.1, 37.2, 35.9, 33.2, 36.9, 36.0, 33.9, 33.7, 34.3, 35.1))
# Annual delta for interpolation
annual$delta<-c(NA, diff(annual$share,1))
# Quarterly table
ref<-data.frame(quarter=paste0("Q", 1:4), nb=1:4)
quart<-merge(annual, ref)
quart<-quart[order(quart$year, quart$quarter),]

# quarterly value calculation with evolution (loop)
quart$quarterly<-NA
quart$quarterly[1:4]<-quart$share[1:4]/4

for (i in (2:dim(annual)[1])) {     
quart$quarterly[quart$year==annual$year[i]] <- sum(quart$quarterly[quart$year==annual$year[i-1]])/4+ (quart$delta[quart$year==annual$year[i]] * quart$nb[quart$year==annual$year[i]])/10
 }
# /10 : /(1+2+3+4)
# Check :
summary(annual$share == aggregate(quarterly ~ year, data=quart, FUN=sum)[,2])
plot(quart$quarterly, typ="l")
```

It may be ugly, but i prefer to use basic functions to understand the underlyers, so I can adapt my code to other situations.